# Cuando algo se encuentra detrás o delante de una palabra

Tags: adverbios

Surgió una duda respecto a cómo etiquetar amigos en las diferentes redes sociales.

Por ejemplo, se utiliza `@nombre`. Esa `@`, ¿se dice que está delante o detrás del nombre? ¿Qué es lo que define su posición?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mecanismo de etiquetar a alguien usando una arroba (@) en la forma de

> **@nombre**

requiera colocar la arroba  [precediendo](https://dle.rae.es/preceder?m=form) al nombre, **por lo tanto, *delante* del mismo**

> precediendo
>
> 1. tr. Ir **delante** en tiempo, orden o lugar.

---

> [delante](https://dle.rae.es/delante?m=form)
>
> 1. adv. Con prioridad de lugar, en la parte anterior o en sitio detrás del cual hay alguien o algo.
> 2. adv. enfrente.

Lo que define las posiciones relativas de ambos, **es el sentido de la escritura de *izquierda* a *derecha***

Mientras que la definición de detrás dice:

> [detrás](https://dle.rae.es/detr%C3%A1s?m=form)
>
> 1. adv. En la parte posterior, o con posterioridad de lugar, o en sitio delante del cual está alguien o algo.